# How do you load specific columns formatted in parquet into Redshift spectrum?

Tags: amazon-redshift, parquet, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to load specific columns into Redshift Spectrum, but it appears that the data is being loaded positionally, which means it doesn't matter what I put for the column names.

To make this more concrete:

Let's say the data I want to load is stored positionally in parquet as columns A, B, C. I only want column B, so I write:

```
create external table spectrum.Foo(
  B varchar(500)
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://data/';
```

Unfortunately, when I do that, it actually loads the data of A into Foo.B

Is there some extra syntax I need. I scoured the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining the external table does not load data into Redshift -- it simply enables you to query it. If you want to ingest only a subset of the columns you can try the following set of queries:

```
create external table spectrum.Foo(
  A varchar(100), B varchar(100), C varchar(100)
) stored as parquet location 's3://data/';
```

This defines the external schema:

```
create table local_data as select A, C from spectrum.Foo;
```

This will essentially load only the specified columns from the external table into a local table in Redshift. However, you don't need to do that: The advantage of Redshift Spectrum and Parquet is that when you run the query:

```
select A, C from spectrum.Foo;
```

it will only load the data from S3 for the accessed columns, reducing the number of IO operations to S3 and reducing the cost.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, using that code, I get error: `HIVE_UNKNOWN_ERROR: Path is not absolute: s3://data error`. [AWS Forum Discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=780492#780492) has further explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing redshift table, Spectrify provides an easy-to-use method for moving data to Spectrum -- https://github.com/hellonarrativ/spectrify/